# Python source RPMS for centos?

Tags: centos, python, rpm

Anybody have a link to the page where centos source rpms are located?  I'm looking for the python source rpm to build a debug python binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the rpms here:

http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/SRPMS/